# Operations with DATE in bash

Tags: bash, date, rhel5

So I need to create a script that writes in a file details about phone calls. The file needs to contain: 
-CALLING_NUMBER -> which starts with 0742, 0743 and 0744, the rest of the digits being randomly generated ( 10 in total )

-CALLED_NUMBER -> which starts with 07 and the rest of the digits also random

-START_DATE -> the start date of the phone call, in format yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss. For all phone calls, the start date needs to be from the same day and cover all the hours in that day

-END_DATE -> the end date of the phone call, in the same format, greater than the start date, randomly generating the extra seconds between 0-7200

-CALL_TYPE -> if the duration of the call is 1 sec, it return SMS, if it is longer, it returns VOICE

I did the CALLING_NUMBER and the CALLED_NUMBER and the CALL_TYPE is pretty straight forward once you have end and start date. I am having troubles with the start and end date.

GNU bash,version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Thanks!

Comment: Add to your question your OS, version of date command  and your coding efforts.

Comment: So you need randomly generated `start_date`s, all on a same day? Is that day fixed, or is is also random? If it's random, in what range?

Comment: I can see sticking with `bash` 3.2 if you are using macOS, but Linux? You should upgrade to a version that isn't over 10 years old.

Comment: Well in the file I need to have 6000 lines, so I guess the start_date doesn't matter as long as you cover all hours of the day.

Comment: I am doing this on a friends machine. I am pretty new at all this..still in the learning process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate a random `start_date` anchored on a specific day, and then a random `end_date` that is 0-7200 seconds later than that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# all start_date's will be on this day
start_date_anchor="2017-09-01"
# start_date in seconds since Unix epoch
start_date_zero=$(date -d "$start_date_anchor" +%s)
# random offset in seconds from midnight (note: RANDOM is a 15-bit int)
start_date_offset=$(( ((RANDOM<<15)|RANDOM) % 86400 ))
# random start_date in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format
start_date=$(date -d @"$((start_date_zero + start_date_offset))" +"%F %T")

# 0-7200 seconds offset
end_date_offset=$((RANDOM % 7200))
# end_date in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format
end_date=$(date -d @"$((start_date_zero + start_date_offset + end_date_offset))" +"%F %T")

echo "Start date: $start_date"
echo "End date: $end_date"
```

Note we use here:

- `date -d 'some_date' +%s` to convert `some_date` to Unix timestamp (seconds since epoch)
- bash `RANDOM` variable, which returns a random integer in a 15-bit range (0 to 32767) each time it is called/referenced. We can get a 30-bit random integer by combining bits of two 15-bit integers with: `RANDOM<<15 | RANDOM`.
- date arithmetic in seconds
- `date -d @unix_timestamp` to convert Unix timestamp back to human-readable date/time
- `+"%F %T"` format specifier as a shortcut for the `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format